# nuxt-i18n with vue router on nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

Build crashes when trying to add any locale to the i18n config with vue router

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's trying to create localized routes for nuxt-router. Set `strategy: 'no_prefix'`, on i18n config.